# Implement callback endpoint on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, api, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a request to a third-party api from my android app. I am required to add a callback endpoint on my server to receive payment notification on my request.So I need to send this callbackUrl as part of my POST request to this api.From data from this payment notification, I can update my real time database. Since my app is being hosted on firebase. I want to know how I cam implement the callback endpoint on firebase to receive the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the callback the third-party API needs is a [web hook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook), you can implement that with a [HTTP Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

You *may* be able to specify Realtime Database directly as a web hook through its [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data), as long. as you can configure the third-party API to post the value in the request body (as shown in the link).

Comment: Well noted. How do I retrieve data passed to the callbackurl into my app. Do I have to save it to my database first or I can directly retrieve it from the response url

Comment: That depends on which route you go. If you write from the 3rd party API to the Realtime Database, your app will need to listen for updates in the database. If you use Cloud Functions, it's up to you to determine how to bring the data to the client. If the Cloud Function writes it to the database, it's the same as before.